# How to delete a column of a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove the second element from every row of multidimensional array.
I have only found solutions to remove the last array or to remove the last column.
Here's my latest trying, but doesn't work now... Can you help me?

```
<?php
$array = [
    ["item_id" => "1", "item_name" => "a"],
    ["item_id" => "2", "item_name" => "b"], 
    ["item_id" => "3", "item_name" => "c"], 
    ["item_id" => "4", "item_name" => "d", "value" => "10"], 
    ["item_id" => "5", "item_name" => "e", "value" => "11"], 
    ["item_id" => "6", "item_name" => "f", "value" => "12"]
];

foreach($array AS $row)
{

 unset ($row[count($row)-2]);

}

print_r($array);
?>
```

My desired output is:

```
$array = [
    ["item_id" => "1"],
    ["item_id" => "2"], 
    ["item_id" => "3"], 
    ["item_id" => "4", "value" => "10"], 
    ["item_id" => "5", "value" => "11"], 
    ["item_id" => "6", "value" => "12"]
];
```

Comment: The index of `"item_name" => "a"` isn't `1`, it's `"item_name"`. And it's not technically called the "second item", it's called the value with key "item_name". You access that with e.g. `$array[0]["item_name"]`. Please look up associative array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First when you do `unset ($row[count($row)-2]);` you are are just unsetting an index of the `$row` variable which is just a *copy* of the value from your array. So you are not deleting the value in the array.
Secondly, when you do `$row[count($row)-2]` you are assuming your $row has numerical indexes, which is not the case here. You want to delete the `item_name` index so you have to do something like `unset($array[$index]['item_name'])`.

```
for($i = 0, $length = count($array); $i < $length; ++$i)
{
    unset($array[$i]['item_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a `foreach` loop: `array_walk()` applies a user function to every item in an array:

```
array_walk( $arr, function(&$a){unset($a['item_name']);});
                     //    ^^^ Use reference here to 
                     //        work on the original array
```

For example:

```
$arr = [
    ["item_id" => "1", "item_name" => "a"],
    ["item_id" => "2", "item_name" => "b"], 
    ["item_id" => "3", "item_name" => "c"], 
    ["item_id" => "4", "item_name" => "d", "value" => "10"], 
    ["item_id" => "5", "item_name" => "e", "value" => "11"], 
    ["item_id" => "6", "item_name" => "f", "value" => "12"]
];

array_walk( $arr, function(&$a){unset($a['item_name']);});

print_r($arr);

/* Output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (    [item_id] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (    [item_id] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (   [item_id] => 4
            [value] => 10
        )
    [4] => Array
        (   [item_id] => 5
            [value] => 11
        )
    [5] => Array
        (   [item_id] => 6
            [value] => 12
        )
)
*/
```

Comment: array_walk should not be used for structural changes as it can be unpredictable, as per the PHP manual: "Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable." - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php